# How to make Desktop(Windows 10 , 8.1,8) build in cocos creator

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

[image]My project is developed in cocos creator v1.8.2 and it is also working on v2.1.0. and it is running on
Android, iPhone and web. Now I want to make a build for Desktop(windows build), I have install vs2017, python2.7.10, ndkr19c and ant etc, on my windows 10 Pc. when I making a Debug/Release Build its complete success and make .exe file, and when I run that exe file its give error like

lastly I make test project and make a build from cocos creator, and run that project on vs2017 its give same error see image

[image: test project[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QnR5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have find the solution for this
Step1-> First check your environment is all set correctly or not for that you can visit [here](https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/creator/manual/en/publish/setup-native-development.html)
and must follow all step and version.

Step2-> After all configuration make demo project and make a build for Windows in cocos creator, the open vs2017 as administrator and load project and build that project. If you have have done everything ok then your project will run. if not then reinstall vs2017.and make sure everything is installed like [this](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/windows-build-error-of-empty-project-in-v2-0-9-v2-0-8/46645/14)

Step3-> If you get dll error like msvcr100,msvcr110,msvcr120 etc then downlode this dll files from internet for 32 bit and 64 bit and put this files in C://windows>system32 and C://windows>SysWOW64, and restart your computer.